# How many is too many ID in an html page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a Single Page App and we are having a conversation with the QA person whereas we should fill in the page with ID on each section of the page to write more specific tests.

I was wondering if there is a "best practice" or a known limit on how many IDs can be present in a single html page at any given time.

We could potentially end up with hundreds at a time. Will it bloat up the browser?

*(please let me know if there is a better place to ask this question)*

Comment: use as many ID's as your code uses

Comment: Old, but relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2068553/5768908

Comment: Thanks, @GerardoFurtado, I found that question very interesting.

Comment: I would still prefer to use `id` and `class` with the standard best practices of html in mind.

The difference between both is that an ID can be used to identify an element, but a class can be used to identify more than one.

So, for instance if you want to assign red font color, I would set it as a `class` and not an `id` because I may use that again for another line of text. If I were to set it as ID, then I would have to create another ID to do the same thing, which is taking up space. 

So to minimize the CSS file size, I would still prefer the best practices for html structure.

Comment: Adding an id to every element in the DOM would not "bloat up the browser". It will not effect performance at all.

Comment: Just go ahead. Impact on end-user is zero. And you will just waste your time doing extravagant workarounds. Although IMO on tests, it should select a section on a page by a most meaningful selector possible, for maintainability and stability, like `header h1` instead of `#header-title-top`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am getting a single element from the DOM, then I add 5000 elements with ids to the DOM and then select the 1000th one. As you can see 5000 is easy for the browser so I would say that is more than enough for any page. Feel free to play with the numbers and see where performance starts to degrade or make the DOM more complex that a heap of unstyled spans.

```js
let start = performance.now();
let div = document.getElementById('single');
console.log(performance.now() - start);

for (let i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.id = 'test_' + i;
  span.innerText = i + ' ';
  document.body.appendChild(span);
}

start = performance.now();
div = document.getElementById('test_1000');
console.log(performance.now() - start);
console.log(div.innerText);
```

```html
<div id="single"></div>
```

I just updated it to work in IE and it was still sub millisecond.

Comment: This is a much more thorough explanation of why there can be many IDs in the page. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding extra ID's, you could add class names that end up minified on Production, or, what I see as a better version, create your own data attribute. For example:

#### In Development Mode:

```html
<button class='login __qa-login-confirm-button'>

// Using data attribute:
<button class='login' data-qa='login-confirm-button'>
```

Class names are usually switched to something of the sort by most SPA frameworks.

#### In Production:

```html
<button class='ax1 vbw'> 

// Or, using data attribute, the data-qa could be stripped down in Prod:
<button class='ax1'>
```

Using your own data- attribute would require a bit more work on the deployment to remove them, but has the added benefit of no overhead for your application and being more clear and less error-prone (for example, in the SPA we develop, sometimes a class name that is meant for QA is accidentally edited or deleted).

Comment: I like this idea, as it will probably work out very well during QA element detection.